# Windows Mobile 5 TabControl

Tags: windows-mobile, tabcontrol

I would like to change how the TabControl looks on the mobile device. Currently, it has its page tabs at the bottom of the TabControl. Unfortunately, the customer wants them at the top of the TabControl. Is there an easy way to get the desired placement (i.e., a property)? Or am I going to be faced with rolling my own TabControlEx? If the latter, any recommendation for how-to sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to roll your own.  The native TabControl has it at the bottom (under WinMo) and there's no way to change that.

Comment: Do you have any online references that might help in the rolling?

Comment: Not offhand.  Microsoft's reasoning for putting the tabs at the bottom is so that the user's hand doesn't obscure the screen while navigating between tabs.  Typically when I explain this to a customer (and tell them the added cost of hand-rolling a whole new tab control) they've always decided in the end to use tabs at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for the information. We just shifted the project to WinCE and the page tabs are now on the top of the TabControl.

Comment: Yep, CE behaves differently than WinMo (menus and menu bars behave differently between the platforms as well).

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at Resco TabControl.

www.resco.net